# No me muestra el calendario con bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

tengo un problema al darle click al calendario no lo muestra.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    
  </head>
  <body>


  <div class="container">
    <h1>DMG</h1>
    <h3>Sub</h3>
    <br />
    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
          <div class="container">

              <div class='col-md-5'>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                          <input type='text' class="form-control" value="hjasdb" />
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class='col-md-5'>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i> Exportar PDF</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    

  </div>
  
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

  
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: Bootstrap no incluye una función o librería tipo "datepicker" por defecto. Debes escoger entre alguna de las muchas disponibles como [por ejemplo esta](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) y asumiendo que no usas bower, npm, ... descargar el js y el css e [incluir el script y el link al css en tu código html](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/).

Comment: ya lo hise pero no funciona

Answer (score 1):

Debes incluir las librerias de moment.js y de bootstrap-datetimepicker.js si quieres que funcione.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    
  </head>
  <body>


  <div class="container">
    <h1>DMG</h1>
    <h3>Sub</h3>
    <br />
    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
          <div class="container">

              <div class='col-md-5'>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                          <input type='text' class="form-control" value="hjasdb" />
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class='col-md-5'>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick=""><i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i> Exportar PDF</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    

  </div>
  
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  

  
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola tengo una duda, en que parte de mi codigo pongo la funcion js?.

Comment: ya puse los dos scripts que pusiste pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Como ves aqui si funciona.  El javascript lo puedes poner donde sea, solo tienes que agregar el tag `<script>`

Comment: ya lo hise y no jala

Comment: Entonces ponlo despues que agregas todos los otros scripts

Comment: lo puse abajo de mi ultimo div y no jala

Comment: ya lo puse abajo del ultimo script y tampoco entonces puse un alert y cuando regresco si entra pero le pico al calendario y no hace nada

Comment: Has descargado la librería y la has puesto en una ruta desde la que la puedes cargar con el tag de script?